# pandas expand dataframe column with tuples, into multiple columns and rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame where one column contains elements that are a list containing several tuples.    I want to turn each tuple in to a column for each element and create a new row for each tuple.  So this code shows what I mean and the solution I came up with:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame(data=[['a','b',[(1,2,3),(6,7,8)]],
                      ['c','d',[(10,20,30)]]], columns=['one','two','three'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['one', 'two', 'A', 'B','C'])

print(a)

for index,item in a.iterrows():
    for xtup in item.three:
        temp = pd.Series(item)
        temp['A'] = xtup[0]
        temp['B'] = xtup[1]
        temp['C'] = xtup[2]
        temp = temp.drop('three')
        df2 = df2.append(temp)

print(df2)
```

The output is:

```
  one two                   three
0   a   b  [(1, 2, 3), (6, 7, 8)]
1   c   d          [(10, 20, 30)]



  one two   A   B   C
0   a   b   1   2   3
0   a   b   6   7   8
1   c   d  10  20  30
```

Unfortunately, my solution takes 2 hours to run on 55,000 rows!  Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We do explode column then explode row

```
a=a.explode('three')
a=pd.concat([a,pd.DataFrame(a.pop('three').tolist(),index=a.index)],axis=1)
  one two   0   1   2
0   a   b   1   2   3
0   a   b   6   7   8
1   c   d  10  20  30
```

Comment: Wow!  That reduced the time to 680ms ... and introduced me to 'explode'.  Tnx

Comment: I've asked a question about the reverse of this process here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62247756/pandas-efficiently-compress-columns-into-column-with-lists-of-tuples

Comment: you can also add columns=['A','B','C'] to the pd.DataFrame arguments to adjust col names