# pandas efficiently compress columns into column with lists of tuples

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe representing groups of exchanges between account holders.  The data shows the interacting accounts and items exchanged.  Sometimes there is a clear match but sometimes the totals of items exchanged match but you can't tell exactly what amount was exchanged between individuals.

The desired input output is as follows:

```
  id group   rx   tx
0  A     x   50    0
1  B     x    0   50
2  A     y  210    0
3  B     y    0   50
4  C     y    0  350
5  D     y  190    0
  group                                          exchanges
0     x                                       [(B, A, 50)]
1     y  [(unk, A, 210), (B, unk, 50), (C, unk, 350), (unk, D, 190)]
```

Currently I'm using 'groupby' and 'apply' like this:

```
def sort_out(x):
  # create the row to be returned
  y = pd.Series(index=['group','exchanges'])
  y['group'] = x.group.iloc[0]
  y['exchanges'] = []

  # Find all rx and make tuples list
  # determine source and destinations
  sink = [tuple(i) for i in x.loc[x['rx'] != 0][[
      'id', 'rx'
  ]].to_records(index=True)]
  source = [tuple(i) for i in x.loc[x['tx'] != 0][[
      'id', 'tx'
  ]].to_records(index=True)] 

  # find match
  match = []
  for item in source:
      match = [o for o in sink if o[2] == item[2]]
      if len(match):
          y['exchanges'].append((item[1], match[0][1], match[0][2]))
          sink.remove(match[0])
          continue

  # handle the unmatched elements
  tx_el = x.loc[~x['tx'].isin(x['rx'])][[
      'id', 'tx']].to_records(index=True)
  rx_el = x.loc[~x['rx'].isin(x['tx'])][[
      'id', 'rx']].to_records(index=True)

  [y['exchanges'].append((item[1], 'unk', item[2])) for item in tx_el]
  [y['exchanges'].append(('unk', item[1], item[2])) for item in rx_el]

  return y

b = a.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: sort_out(x))
```

This approach takes at best 7 hours on a ~20 million rows.  I think the big hurdle is 'groupby'-'apply'.  I was recently introduced to 'explode'.  From there I looked at 'melt' but it doesn't seem to what I'm looking for.  Any suggestions for improvements?

[ANOTHER ATTEMPT]

Based on YOBEN_S suggestions I tried the following.  Part of the challenge is matching, part is keeping track of which is transmitting (tx) and which is receiving (rx). So I cheat by adding a tag explicitly i.e. direction ['dir'].  I also use a nested ternary but I'm not sure if that's very performant:

```
a['dir'] = a.apply(lambda x: 't' if x['tx'] !=0 else 'r', axis=1)
a[['rx','tx']]=np.sort(a[['rx','tx']].values,axis=1)

out = a.drop(['group','rx'],1).apply(tuple,1).groupby([a['group'],a.tx]).agg('sum') \
   .apply(lambda x: (x[3],x[0],x[1]) if len(x)==6 else  
     ((x[0],'unk',x[1]) if x[2]=='t' else ('unk',x[0],x[1]))
    ).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
out=df.drop('group',1).apply(tuple,1).groupby(df['group']).agg(list).to_frame('exchange').reset_index()
  group                                           exchange
0     x                           [(A, 50, 0), (B, 0, 50)]
1     y  [(A, 210, 0), (B, 0, 50), (C, 0, 350), (D, 190...
```

Update

```
df[['rx','tx']]=np.sort(df[['rx','tx']].values,axis=1)
out=df.drop(['group','rx'],1).apply(list,1).groupby([df['group'],df.tx]).agg('sum').apply(set).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
out
group
x                               [{50, A, B}]
y    [{50, B}, {D, 190}, {210, A}, {C, 350}]
dtype: object
```

Comment: That takes 1/8th the time in repl.it.  But I'm still figuring out how it works eg. 'group' is dropped but then used in the 'groupby', or how does matching take place?

Comment: @MikeB2019x this is so called `pd.serise groupby`

Comment: I went through it piece by piece.  What remains to do is the matching e.g. for group x 'exchange' should be [(A, B, 50)].

Comment: closer I think but I'm getting dicts:  x  [{0, A}, {50, B}] vice x [(A,B,50)].